# How to call IFrame from web page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

How can I call an IFrame from a view?

In my current view I have this HTML.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="border:dashed;" id="mapContainer">
                <iframe src="MyIframe" name="myTest"></iframe>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The MyIframe is a cshtml file that exists in the same location as the above view resides in.

When I run the application I get a 404 - Not found.
What is the proper way to load an IFrame in an existing view?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I just need to change my source to:
src=@Url.Action("action", "controller")